# io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer caused by too many data query

Tags: kotlin, graphql, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I did look at the similar questions, but in my case it's a bit difference. I assume that this exception caused by too many data query. I tried remove some data from my database and I got it work, but if I added more data this exception will be thrown again. I use **graphql** subscription query with **mongodb**. This is how I do the query.

```
@GrapQLSubscription
fun findAllEmployees(): Publisher<List<Employee>> {
  return employeeRepository.findAll()
                           .collectList()
                           .flatMap { produceGraphQlSubscription(it) }
}
```

So how do I resolve this issue ? I want to keep pagination as my final card. Are there any other way around like set webflux timeout or etc?

Comment: One quick workaround is to reduce flatMap concurrency (number of concurrently launched operations, and in your case I think, the number of connections). To do so, add the concurrency argument to flatmap: `.flatMap({ produceGraphQlSubscription(it) }, 10)`. Another possible solution would be to create some sort of client/connection pool reused by the `produceGraphQlSubscription` function.

Comment: Oh wait, I've missed the `collectList` part. Mmh... I think we need more details to understand the problem. Can you also attach the code of `produceGraphQlSubscription` ?